# Error with Cordova using VS 2015 :Error bld00401

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to get Cordova to work using visual studio 2015, however when I open a new project and run that stndard template, it fails to build and it gives the following errors:

1st Error:

```
BLD401 Error: BLD00401: Could not find module C:\Users\Rami Kalai\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js. 

Please Go to Tools -->
Options --> 
Tools for Apache Cordova --> 
Cordova Tools --> 
Clear Cordova Cache and try building again. 
BlankCordovaApp1
```

2nd Error:

```
Error installing local npm package. BlankCordovaApp1    
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets 279
```

Any help is much appreciated.

I am running on windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cordova app cache as the first error suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a bug that we introduced in Update 6. We've fixed this in Update 7. Please go to our blog and click the download link to install:

http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/03/01/announcing-update-7.html

You should also see a notification for the update. Sorry for the trouble.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)