# Apache Cordova Tools with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, npm-install

I am totally new to Apache Cordova tools with VS 2015. I just tried to create basic initial project, added nothing more and trying to build it, but it fails everytime.

For the specific error I get, I performed all the steps mentioned at:
 [Configuring Apache Cordova with VS2015](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac).

I am not able to get rid of this error and run the most basic project.

Here is my sample code: https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApUTYQW5TdbIgzrPGeUkxWVmmy0Z

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Have you tried clear the cordova cache as mentioned in the error log?

Comment: @Deepak Pathak Did you tried out the solution? Did it helped? Please revert as bounty is running out

Comment: Elvis Xia - MSFT - I tried clearing the cache, then closing and re-opening the project, doing a clean rebuild. But no luck yet. :(

Comment: This project is missing an [mcve] because the code is not in the question itself, which is a Stack Overflow requirement. Would you edit this question to make that amendment? Thankfully the external link still works.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and was able to solve it using the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688018/4045156

The solution is for a slightly different problem, but in my case it did resolve it. :)

EDIT: here's the solution from that post:

> Close all VS instances
>
> cd %appdata%\"..\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools"
>
> rename CoreCon folder to something else
>
> Launch VS again.

Comment: Sam - I did the same, rebuilt the project but still the same error :(

Comment: Hmmm...errors like these can be extremely annoying. Sometimes it comes down to reinstalling Visual Studio because it's honestly just a thoroughly confused program (though still very useful).

Comment: Sam - So, do you suggest a "Repair" of VS 2015 installation. I have community edition installed.

Comment: Either that or a reinstall. It seems like you might be at that "last resort" point. :/

Comment: Sam - Okay, doing a repair... I don't know why things screwed up for me...

Comment: Nothing helped guyz, I don't know what is the issue here :(

If someone can help and have some free time, I can share my screen to fix this?

Comment: Would love to help but I really wouldn't know what to suggest. Have you tried a complete uninstall and reinstall? (I know it's a pain)

Comment: I just did a repair for TACO, I have the community edition of VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the official link - [configure VS tools for Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#vstac) which you are following,

> If you see unexpected errors when trying to build the Blank App template after installing Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, you can try clearing your cache and reinstalling the Cordova CLI pre-processor, vs-tac, on your PC.Typically, this is only necessary if you try to build a Cordova app and see the error Cannot find module [modulename].

For other errors, you may have to look at [workarounds link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-general-readme/).

According to me, clearing cache should resolve the issue or this issue would have got introduced in latest version of Visual Studio once again.

I also suggest you to look at the following SO posts which should help you out in this issue.

1. [VS dont work with TACO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679802/visual-studio-2015-wont-work-with-tools-for-apache-cordova)
2. [Error with cordova using VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785503/error-with-cordova-using-vs-2015-error-bld00401?rq=1)

Hope this helps. Cheers.